# How to get a 'array of objects' from json.dumps (python)

Tags: python, json, postgresql, psycopg2

I am making an API using python psycopg2 and my requests will return JSON from the query results.

It turns out that by doing 'json.dumps' my 'List of records' loses keys.

Is there any solution for this?

```
result = db_utils.execute_query(query, fetch_all=True)
print(result)
[Record(id=1,name=John),Record(id=2,name=Doe)]
```

**What I get:**

```
json_str = json.dumps(result, indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str)
print(json_str)
[[1,'John'],[2,'Doe']]
```

**What I want:**

```
print(json_str)
[{'id':1, 'name':'John'},{'id':2,'name':'Doe'}]
```

Comment: Please show in code what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Why not get your results out this way:

```
import psycopg2    
def fetch_records():
try:
    connection = psycopg2.connect(user="postgres_user",
                                     password="your_pass",
                                     host="your host",
                                     port="5432",
                                     database="db_name")
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    
    query = "select * from your_table"
    cursor.execute(postgreSQL_select_Query)
    result = cursor.fetchall() #gets you your result in the format [{key:vals,...}{key:vals,...}...]
    return result
```

Comment: I'm using Flask as API management. If I return the 'fetchall' result as the request result, I get the following error: 'TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, dict, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a list.'

Comment: return json.dumps(result)